# Counting Files with Bash

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I'm trying to keep my function inspect_files to the principle of single responsibility, I know I could easily calculate the file count inside of that function and print it there, but is there a more elegant solution to count files than this?

(Note, I don't want a recursive file count.)

```
# Snippet:

dir_name="$HOME/$1"

inspect_files() {
  local content
  for content in "$dir_name"/*; do
    printf "%s\n" "${content##*/}"
  done
  count_files "$dir_name"
}

count_files() {
  local count
  local dir="$1"
  count=$(ls -1 "$dir_name" | wc -l)
  printf "\nTotal: %d\n" "$count"
}

if is_found "$dir_name"; then
  inspect_files
else
  echo 'Not a directory.'
fi
```

Comment: use the wc utility. `wc -l` prints the number of lines. `ls $dir_name/* | wc -l` should get you running. or `count=$(ls $dir_name/* | wc -l)` to store the output in count.

Comment: Should be `ls -1` to ensure each filename is listed one per line for use with `wc`. Not all existing `ls` implementations do that, whether the output is to a terminal device or not. There is also the problem of aliases being used for `ls` with the `-C` option specified, so the `-1` option must be used to override this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
list_and_count_files()
{
  local content
  local count
  count=0
  for content in "${1:-.}"/*; do
    printf "%s\n" "${content##*/}"
    ((count++))
  done
  printf "\nTotal: %d\n" "$count"
}
```

This name is a more accurate description of what your original function does.  Note that the directory to be analyzed is passed as an argument to the function, but defaults to `.` (the current directory) if you don't pass anything.  This decouples the function from the variable `$dir_name`, which is much better for isolation.

Comment: That was my original solution, I just wanted to know is there a better way of counting files other than the way I've written it. I wanted to avoid having to print all of the files in the directory and print the number of files in the same function. It makes me "uneasy" because I feel that it should only do one thing. I like what you did with the array argument, I've always had trouble doing that haha.

Comment: Your function as written has unnecessary coupling via the variable `$dir_name` (as noted in my commentary).  As written, it calls another function too.  If you want the functions independent, don't have your `inspect_files` function call `count_files`; call the functions separately.  However, if you're always going to call them in tandem (so you always want the list and the count), then you're better off with a single function that does the complete job.  If you'd ever call `count_files` without first calling `inspect_files`, then two functions are warranted. It depends on how you'll use them.

Comment: I see, I think I might've thought too far in depth with this problem. When I first tackled it I just printed the files and counted them in the same function as you said. I then came back to it trying to see if I could isolate the two. You're right, sometimes it's better to keep things simple. Appreciate the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The next function:

```
inspect_files() {
    find "$1/" -type f -maxdepth 1 -print0 | grep -zc .
}
```

return the plain file count in a given direcotry, e,g:

```
 tmpcount=$(inspect_files /tmp)
 echo "File count in /tmp is: $tmpcount"
```

if you want count everything (not only plain files) use a simlper:

```
inspect_files() {
    find "$1/" -maxdepth 1 -print0 | grep -zc .
}
```

The slash after `"$1/"` ensure you counting in the directories what are symbolic links, like

```
$ ls -ld /tmp
lrwxr-xr-x@ 1 root  wheel  11 27 jul  2012 /tmp -> private/tmp
```

Comment: Find is a command I've got to use more, it seems like it really reduces the whole idea of having to loop through the directory. I'll read the man pages a little more on this command, thanks for the answer as well!

Answer (score 0):

I think that a more elegant and performant solution to count files can be this one:

```bash
find "$dir_name" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -ignore_readdir_race -printf x | wc -m
```

So that your counting fuction would look like this:

```bash
count_files() {
  local count
  local dir="$1"
  count=$(find "$dir_name" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -ignore_readdir_race -printf x | wc -m)
  printf "\nTotal: %d\n" "$count"
}
```

This version works by printing an "x" for each item in the directory, then counting the characters with wc -m. It has a very low memory footprint, does no sorting and you can redirect output to a file to count asynchronously - for very large directories - (side-note: this counts also hidden files and subdirs, so you eventually have to filter them out with `-and -not -name '.*'`).

Tip: `-ignore_readdir_race` makes `find` ignore errors due to deletion of files during the operation (maybe you don't want to stop operating on the files in the directory during the count).

There is plenty of questions about counting files with bash, so I imagined that it can be helpful to use a function (like you did) to simplify the operation. I'll copy your approach and put it in my .barshrc and .zshrc ;-)